# How to delete one polygon from a multi polygon record in a spatialite database using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a spatialite database with multi polygon records within the database. When i try to edit these records i cannot delete just one of the polgons for a specific record. It only allows me to delete the entire record which may have up to 5 or 6 polygons associated with the record and i only want to delete one of these polygons from within the multi polygon record.

I can get around it by exporting the record as a Shapefile, exploding to a multi part then deleting the polygon i need to delete, then taking the multi part back to a single part and then inserting it back into the spatialite database. A long and annoying process !!!!

Is there a quicker way of doing this?? I really hope so !!

Regards,

Paul

Comment: Is there something specific about the polygon you want to delete - is it always the first one, the last one (n'th one), always in a certain area, or something that can be used to identify which one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you can use the delete part tool in the "advanced digitizing" toolbar.
In the main menu under "View > Toolbars", activate the advanced digitizing toolbar. Enable editing on your layer and select the multipart feature that you need to edit. Select the "Delete Part" tool (see image below). Finally select a vertex of the part you want to delete. That should remove the individual part.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Great !! Does the job so thanks a lot for your help . . .